# vb.net a forms "new" routine is being called before I even invoke the form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a form called "partmanager". On it is a button to show another form "parteditor" to allow editing details of a part. Clicking that button will show the form and pass in a variable to the parteditors "new" routine.
My problem is that when the calling form (partmanager) starts, it immediately calls new routine in the parteditor form before it (partmanager) is even initialized so the parteditor form does not get the string that is supposed to be passed in. Later, when the calling form is visible and I click the button to show the parteditor form, new has already been prematurely called and so is not called again and the form does not get the string passed in.
I hope this makes sense!
I can implement a property in the parteditor form and pass in my variable that way prior to showing the form and that will work, thereby not even requiring a "new" routine in the parteditor forms code.
So my question is, is implementing the property the proper way to pass  this variable to the form being called, or am I not properly coding my forms? (I also have an intermediary module called "commands" where I have been defining command procedures, in this case just showing a form.)
any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

here is the code for the button in the calling form:

```
Private Sub EditButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EditButton.Click
   Commands.EditPart(_PartNumber) 'call the editpart command
   Me.Close()
   Me.Dispose()
End Sub
```

here is the code for the form being called:

```
Public Class PartEditForm
    Private _partNumber As String = String.Empty
    Public Sub New(partNumber As String)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        _partNumber = partNumber
       
    End Sub
    Private Sub PartEditForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Label1.Text = _partNumber
    End Sub
End Class
```

and here is the code in my "commands" module for loading/showing the form:

```
Public PartEditForm As New PartEditForm(_partNumber)
Public Sub EditPart(partnumber As String)

   If PartEditForm.IsDisposed Then
      PartEditForm = New PartEditForm(partnumber)
  End If
  PartEditForm.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: `Public partEditForm As PartEditForm = nothing`. The Field should most probably be `private`.

Comment: making that declaration private did not change the behavior, new is still called before I click the button to show the second forn.

Comment: You missed `Public partEditForm As PartEditForm = nothing`. Of course you need to change the condition to `If partEditForm is nothing orelse partEditForm.IsDisposed then ...`

Comment: Might be a little to do with how you've presented you code here, but in your 3rd snip here the line Public PartEditForm As New PartEditForm(_partNumber) looks like a form level variable, that will be initializing the PartEditForm when you intitialize the main form

Comment: @Hursey  That's *the code in my "commands" module* (as the OP is saying). So it's initialized as soon as the Module is used and it creates an instance of that Form (calling its constructor, of course).

Comment: yes, "PartEditForm As New PartEditForm(_partNumber)" is a module level declaration. I guess I need to find a different way to implement my form.

Comment: Questions shouldn't have answers in them.  Post your answer in the answer box below.

Answer (score -1):

you can save the routine in a dim variable and get this on the other form and close the first form or hide but you need get in new var and contine where stop before.